# I got error make the enclosing method "static" or remove this set from SonarLint in android

Tags: android, static, static-methods, greendao, sonarlint

In android studio I am using `SonarLint` for testing the code, I got the error in my activity

> make the enclosing method  "static" or remove this set

I used static variable that i used in `onCreate` method.

Code:

```
 public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Interactor, UserMapView, RecyclerItemClickListener {
    static LoginDao listLogin;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        loginPresenter = new RecyclerviewPresenter();
        loginPresenter.attachedView(this);
        setupRecyclerView();
        listLogin = DataProvider.getLoginDao(this);
    }
    public List < Login > createCollectionPictures() {
        List < Login > pictures;
        pictures = listLogin.loadAll();
        return pictures;
    }
```

> Note: If I don't declare the static I couldn't get the output(variable
>   listlogin should be null) but how to solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create a getter method for that static variable and use that getter method whenever the static variable is required.This will not create an issue as well as it will work as per expectation.I hope this will help you.